# Detect user logged on a computer using Java

Tags: java, active-directory

I want to develop an Java application that can detect the user logged on a Window Domain. These credentials are going to be used to logging on the Java application.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
System.getProperty("user.name")
```

Comment: Can I use this on a Java Web app?

Comment: This is very easy to spoof. -Duser.name=Administrator

Comment: You can change the user.name property on the command line, like any other property.  You can use this in Java web app, but it gives you the user of the web process, not the user sending a request.

Comment: Seems like this doesn't include the domain (if the user is on a Windows domain)

Answer (score 12):

If you need to domain name, you can use this :

```
  com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem NTSystem = new
          com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem();
  System.out.println(NTSystem.getName());
  System.out.println(NTSystem.getDomain());
```

Bye.

Comment: Can I use this on a Java Web app?

Comment: No. This is for a Java application (Windows OS).

Comment: This one is better that the System.getProperty("user.name") example, becouse its very easy to trick the JVM to think there is a different user logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Note: System.getProperty("user.name") will only work if the user launches the application.  If the program is run by System or an application like LANDesk, then the user will come out as "SYSTEM" (under domain "NT AUTHORITY").

In which case, the second solution using NTSystem will return the correct results.