# IIS Windows Integrated Authentication alternative methodologies?

Tags: apache, windows-authentication

On a Mac OSX server with Apache, is there any programming library, framework, etc. that I can get to allow Windows Integrated Authentication? I don't mean just LDAP because the user still has to logon the website before I can get the LOGON_USER. I am looking for something that gets the credentials of the Windows user from the browser (IE). I don't care if it uses LDAP, just as long as the user doesn't have to logon to the intranet website.

I have looked for this with J2EE, PHP, Ruby, and more. I have only found unsupported and inactive mods for Apache or pay for single sign on products, but nothing FOSS that is active.

I found [Detect user logged on a computer using Java web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726249/detect-user-logged-on-a-computer-using-java-web-app). Am I reading it right that that is what I am also asking for?

Apparently, [jcifs](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/ntlmhttpauth.html) is not supposed to be used for this.

Answer (score 0):

Ive heard of [Araas](http://araas.sourceforge.net/), but never used it myself though.

Don't know if thats helpful

Answer (score 0):

mod_ntlm: http://sourceforge.net/projects/modntlm/ might be what you are after

Comment: way too old for me to trust it

Answer (score 0):

You can try mod_auth_sspi, but It doesn't work on apache 2.4 for windows :(